# jquerymobile, ajax and wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, performance, jquery-mobile

The short question:
Should I still use Jquerymobile if I just want a responsive swipe and touch enabled ajax Wordpress Theme?

Long:
I try to make the fastest load-time optimized Wordpress-Theme. Searching for simple swipe gestures was kind of annoying. Jquerymobile seems to work best, but it feels like so much overhead.

Till now I used history.js for AJAX a lot, and I'm happy with it, but I'd like to make a more "proper attempt".

My goal is a fast loading website with the fewest JS/CSS resources possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Could potentially roll your own, extracting just the JQ/JQM code you feel you're going to use in your theme.

Comment: @Twisty that's for sure my attempt at the moment. But I got "suspicous" when I used google trends and saw the usage of JQM. The descent of interest in JQM feels like I'm might be using the wrong tool for the job? Trendslink: [link](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#date=1/2010+61m&cmpt=q&q=jquerymobile&geo=US)